# Is it a good practice to assign data node role to all master nodes in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I have a production system in elasticsearch db, which has billions of records and around 20k transactions per second ( could be more in coming days ).

Currently I have 4 elastic servers which has below roles:

```
"roles" : [
        "data",
        "ingest",
        "master",
        "ml",
        "remote_cluster_client",
        "transform"
      ]
```

- Can we add coordinating node in the above configuration, what if
  coordinating node is down, can we have HA for coordinating node?
- Can we assign data node role to all master nodes or do we need to separate master nodes and data nodes ?

Comment: It depends ;-) There's a [whole section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/high-availability-cluster-design.html) on designing clusters (small and big) for HA in the official documentation. You should go through and come back with more concrete questions based on your specific use case(s) ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Val for sharing the link, it helped me alot for configurating elastic for my usecase. I understand that i have to keep dedicated roles for the nodes ( for my usecase) and should use coordinating node for load balancing. Can you share link for coordinating node HA from the official document?

Comment: Let me brief - I understand that we should not keep more coordinating nodes ( client nodes ) for load balancing . Can we keep 2 coordinating nodes in the cluster ? I also understand based on my research we have to set `node.master: false node.data:false node.ingest:false` . So my question is can I keep 2 coordinating nodes for high availability ?

Comment: "I understand that we should not keep more coordinating nodes" where did you read this?